# Combining count(*) with SQL statements into one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL database (table1 and table 2). I want to write a SQL query that outputs some summary stats in a nicely formatted report.

Let's for an example consider a first SQL query that takes the users over 57 year of age from the first table

```
SELECT count(*) AS OlderThank57
FROM table1
WHERE age >57
```

And from the second table we want to get the number of users that are female

```
SELECT count(*) AS FemaleUsers
FROM table2
WHERE gender = "female"
```

Now I want to have an output like the following

```
Number of Felame users from table 2: 514
Number of users over the age of 57 from table 1: 918
```

What is the best way of generating such a report?

Comment: If you need a "nicely formatted report", then you need to use a reporting tool, not MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer to expand one level from Adrian's answer... return as two separate fields so you could place them separately in a report, or align / format the number, etc

```
SELECT 'Number of Female users from table 2:' as Msg, 
       count(*) as Entries
  FROM table1
  WHERE age >57
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Number of users over the age of 57 from table 1:' as Msg, 
       count(*) as Entries
  FROM table2
  WHERE gender = "female"
```

You might have to force both "Msg" columns to the same padded length, otherwise one might get truncated.  Again, just another option...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT('Number of users over the age of 57 from table 1:', count(*))
  FROM table1
  WHERE age >57
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('Number of Felame users from table 2: ', count(*))
  FROM table2
  WHERE gender = "female"
```

I don't have mysql database to check it, so you might have to cast count(*) to string.

Comment: he wants string output, concat is build in mysql function

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the `WITH ROLLUP` directive when using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), gender FROM table1 GROUP BY gender WITH ROLLUP
```

If you want to get a bit crazy you can always make a series of `IF`s that handles the logic for one or more thing at a time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) IF(gender='female', 'female', IF(age>57, 'older_than_57', '*')) AS switch FROM table1 GROUP BY switch WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

A union is your only option if you don't have a normalized database. Your other option is to better standardize/normalize your db so you can run much more efficient queries.